# Imagens do Dropzone não estão chegando no servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um formulário normal e inseri o drozpone dentro dele seguindo algumas dicas pela comunidade. Quando eu dou o submit, as imagens do dropzone não chega de maneira alguma no servidor, o $_FILES é vazio.

**FORM HTML**

```
   <form class="multi-page-form" method="post" id="form_publish" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="row">
      <!-- Dropzone -->
      <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-block">
            <label>Título do anúncio</label>
            <input class="border" type="text" name="title">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="form-block">
            <label>Palavras-chave</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Insira suas palavras chaves" class="border" data-role="tagsinput" name="keywords" id="tagPlaces">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center">
         <button type="button" id="btn-send-property" class="button button-icon large alt"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Enviar Imóvel</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#my-awesome-dropzone', {
    url: 'User/publish',
    paramName: "files",
    autoDiscover: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFilesize: 3.0,
    maxFiles: 30,
    parallelUploads: 10000,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false
});

$("#btn-send-property").click(function () {
    myDropzone.processQueue();
    $("#form_publish").submit();
});
```

**PHP**

```
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

Comment: O que o var_dump retorna exatamente? O php esta na URL `User/publish`?

Comment: Retorna o valor do input file 'featured_image' que não tem nada haver com o dropzone, o que eu realmente quero não está retornando, sim o php está nessa url

Comment: Exatamente como retorna? Copia e cola o retorno aqui.

Comment: array(1) {
  ["featured_image"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }

Comment: o unico files que retorna é de um outro input, o files do dropzone nao retorna nada...

Comment: A url do navegador esta mudando no momento do upload?

Comment: Com certeza.....

Comment: Então esta errado, no Dropzone o upload é feito por Ajax e então não deveria mudar a URL, **com certeza** você esta usando o Dropzone de maneira errada.......

Comment: É que da forma que estou fazendo o dropzone não se encaixa, mas vlw por ajudar

Comment: Tenho certeza que é você quem esta pensando de maneira errada sobre o funcionamento do transporte de dados HTTP, tenho certeza que se souber dividir as tarefas do problema poderá fazer o upload previamente e depois fazer um POST normal para suas tarefas existentes, assim que possível vou formular uma resposta, só lhe peço que coloque o código como esta atualmente para entender sua necessidade.